# C# - How to get current user picture

Tags: c#, windows, image

How can I get the image of the logged in user in c#?

Comment: Ask them nicely to upload one for you?
But seriously, what do you mean?

Comment: What do you already have set up, what have you tried? First step is to get a camera and take their photo or get them to upload them...

Comment: I guess check for a camera attached to a computer, snap a picture, and cross your fingers.

Comment: I'm guessing here, but most likely the user is referring to a photo of a domain user stored in perhaps an Active Directory property or extension attribute.

Comment: @Other comments; :D But I assumed he meant the user account picture

Answer (score 4):

That is not possible on each OS; but on the OS'es where it is possible:

**For Windows Vista or later:**

> That image is located in
>   C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp\UserName.bmp

if the user is a domain user, it will be `"DOMAIN+UserName.bmp"` (Yes, the '+' is part of the filename)

Comment: There has got to be a documented api call for that. Hard coding that will make Raymond very sad.

Comment: On my W7, domain system this checks for me out, however the "UserName" portion is truncated at 8 characters (of my 13 char username).  This may be because of the embedded '.' in the username (bug or intentional, who knows...)

Comment: @asawyer I'm very sorry for Raymond (who is Raymond?) but I can't find any documented api on this... http://searock.bplaced.net/retrieve-username-and-windows-account-picture

Comment: @Rhapsody His posts are always gold, but I was thinking of these two in particular:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/03/22/10144082.aspx, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/11/03/55532.aspx

Comment: This function helped me to locate the local app data folder. Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpeicalFolder.LocalApplicationData) which would return C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\

Comment: I don't get it why it's not the accepted answer. Even beginner programmer can implement this information (considering remarks in comments) in a couple of neat and compatible ways.

Answer (score 2):

Try Ths::

```
    public static Image GetUserimage()
    {  

        if (File.Exists(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)+@"\Temp\"+Environment.UserName+".bmp"))
        {
            return Image.FromFile(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) + @"\Temp\" + Environment.UserName + ".bmp");
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this for windows 10

The user picture is located at 
C:/users/username/appdata/romaing/microsoft/windows/account pictures/

Answer (score 0):

For current user, and ANY user on a Microsoft Windows instance, there is a NuGet package for this (and here goes the shameless plug):

https://github.com/HTD/Woof.System

For those interested in source code and voodoo magic involved.

For those interested in just making it work, use NuGet package Woof.System, then you use the feature like this:

Get the small current user bitmap for WPF:

```
var userBitmapSmall = new BitmapImage(new Uri(SysInfo.GetUserPicturePath()));
```

Get the small OTHER user bitmap for WPF:

```
var userBitmapSmall = new BitmapImage(new Uri(SysInfo.GetUserPicturePath("John")));
```

Get the small and LARGE ANY user bitmap for WPF:

```
var smallBitmapPath = SysInfo.GetUserPicturePath("John", out var largeBitmapPath);
var smallBitmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri(smallBitmapPath));
var largeBitmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri(largeBitmapPath));
```

The solution contained in the library is based on undocumented `Shell32.dll` calls present in Windows Vista and newer and undocumented registry keys present in Windows 8 and newer.

How to get the profile picture of a user logged with Microsoft Account is my own discovery, I haven't found the solution anywhere, it's probably Microsoft's sweet secret.

What's important, solution that can be googled are incomplete in many ways:

- without Win32 API the user profile picture could be either not present in temporary directory, can be deleted, can be inaccessible for a regular user to read.
- without using undocumented registry key and undocumented Win32 API features retrieving profile picture for Microsoft Account user is impossible.

If you find any bugs or incompatibility in this solution please open an issue on GitHub.

Tested with a couple of versions of Windows 10 (stable and developers build).
I tested it with local and Microsoft Accounts.

BTW: If the user name doesn't exist, the method returns a path to "default" profile picture.

NOTE: The package depends on .NET Framework and is incompatible with .NET Core and .NET Standard due to the strong dependency on Win32 API (and thus not cross platform). There are other Woof libraries compatible with .NET Standard. They seem undocumented, however they contain XML documentation available for Visual Studio and the source code on GitHub allows figuring out how they work. Woof libraries are in constant active development, so it's a safe choice.

Comment: There are several undocumented ways. One of them is by reading **IPropertyStore** and **PKEY_SAM_UserPicture** key

Comment: A readme.txt on that repo would go a long way into explaining what is going on :)