# C# Get user picture (Avatar)

Tags: c#, windows-7, image

I'm referring to [C# - How to get current user picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570113/c-how-to-get-current-user-picture) but I never found a solution. (I'm working on Win7 OS)

For some users, the picture is located on

> C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp\UserName.bmp

(where UserName is user nickname) for others users this path throws FileNotFoundException but pictures exists.

Where I can find information about the path or real picture? There is a registry that contains this information?

Comment: You should consider upvoting good answers to your questions (including but not limited to the ones you accept)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This [blog post](http://joco.name/2010/12/06/i-discovered-the-new-windows-user-tile-api/) shows how to set the user tile (picture). In a comment near the end (Michael Anthony, Apr 10, 22:45), the commenter describes how to get the picture. I've gathered the info into a C# snippet. Remember that this is based on an undocumented Windows Shell function.

```
    using System;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Drawing;

    [DllImport("shell32.dll", EntryPoint = "#261", 
               CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, PreserveSig = false)]
    public static extern void GetUserTilePath(
      string username, 
      UInt32 whatever, // 0x80000000
      StringBuilder picpath, int maxLength);

    public static string GetUserTilePath(string username)
    {   // username: use null for current user
        var sb = new StringBuilder(1000);
        GetUserTilePath(username, 0x80000000, sb, sb.Capacity);
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public static Image GetUserTile(string username)
    {
        return Image.FromFile(GetUserTilePath(username));
    }
```

Note that this Shell function creates the file \Users\<USER>\AppData...\<USER>.bmp and returns its filename.

Also, I've tested it on Win7. I have no idea of its compatibility with former Windows versions.

Credits to [Joco](http://joco.name/2010/12/06/i-discovered-the-new-windows-user-tile-api/) and [Michael Anthony](http://www.facebook.com/michaelarockett).

Comment: Great. Now I'll try this snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I have found relevant information at `\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Volatile Envirnment`, but not the exact path.

My guess is that the avatar is always at `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp\` and the file name itself can be found from this algorithm:

```
// Note that $XYZ$ means \HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Volatile Envirnment\XYZ
if $USERDOMAIN$ = "" then
    return $USERNAME$.Substring(0, $USERNAME$.IndexOf('.'));
else
    return $USERDOMAIN$ + "+" + $USERNAME$.Substring(0, $USERNAME$.IndexOf('.'));
```

Again, just a guess.

P.S.: There is `Volatile Environment` for all users, if you look at `\HKEY_USERS`. If you want a specific user, iterate over all users and check in the `Volatile Environment` for the user name (the sub-keys of `\HKEY_USERS` are just random strings, so you must look inside).

Comment: Note the part about the ``.``. I added that because my username is abc.xyz and the file is DOMAIN+abc.bmp.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good info. But I don't read the path for user picture, so I think that this info should be stored into another place. I've found username.dat within C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\User Account pictures. There is a way to read .dat files?

Comment: Only way I know of (and it's not my area) is treat it as a byte[], and extract the text from the end of the .dat file (I don't know which text editor you are using, but note that there are null characters between the text characters - probably as a security measure against ``grep`` and the like).

Comment: I've tried, but the file is empty (0 bytes). There must be a way to get user pictures....

Comment: On my machine there are 2 .dat files in that folder. One of them is empty, the second has what you want. If you don't see the second one, make sure you can see hidden files and that your Explorer window is running with Administrator permissions (not sure that is needed, but worth a try). It really should be there.