# Get default User Account Profile Picture on Windows Vista > 8

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

How can we get the user's profile picture they're using in WIndows 7 and Windows 8? (I'm mainly wanting this for Windows 8). So far I have only seen a bunch of forum posts that say it cannot be done, but I see apps left right and center that can do it.

Comment: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Account-picture-name-sample-912baff1

Comment: @jbabey - surely that should have been an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: Sufficient research was done, but did not find anything for Windows 7 and below. I no longer have Windows 7 (or Vista), so I need to know that the code I find will work instead of relying on answers written by people who state that it's not a guaranteed way to get the profile picture. Thanks for the link; it did notshow up in any of the results.

Comment: That link is for Store apps only, not winforms and not wpf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Serge - appTranslator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253833/c-sharp-get-user-picture-avatar):

This [blog post](http://joco.name/2010/12/06/i-discovered-the-new-windows-user-tile-api/) shows how to set the user tile (picture). In a comment near the end (Michael Anthony, Apr 10, 22:45), the commenter describes how to get the picture. I've gathered the info into a C# snippet. Remember that this is based on an undocumented Windows Shell function.

```
    using System;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Drawing;

    [DllImport("shell32.dll", EntryPoint = "#261", 
               CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, PreserveSig = false)]
    public static extern void GetUserTilePath(
      string username, 
      UInt32 whatever, // 0x80000000
      StringBuilder picpath, int maxLength);

    public static string GetUserTilePath(string username)
    {   // username: use null for current user
        var sb = new StringBuilder(1000);
        GetUserTilePath(username, 0x80000000, sb, sb.Capacity);
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public static Image GetUserTile(string username)
    {
        return Image.FromFile(GetUserTilePath(username));
    }
```

Note that this Shell function creates the file \Users\<USER>\AppData...\<USER>.bmp and returns its filename.

Also, I've tested it on Win7. I have no idea of its compatibility with former Windows versions.

Credits to [Joco](http://joco.name/2010/12/06/i-discovered-the-new-windows-user-tile-api/) and [Michael Anthony](http://www.facebook.com/michaelarockett).

Comment: @One Man Crew It's very helpful!